The Riesz representation theorem and probability density functions?
The Riesz representation theorem asserts that if the linear functional $L:C[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is bounded (and hence continuous), then there exists an $\alpha\in BV[a,b]$ with $\operatorname{Var}_{[a,b]}\alpha = ||L||$ and such that
$$
L(f):=\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)d\alpha(x),\quad\forall f\in C[a,b].
$$
My desire is to work with this representation in the context of probability theory. In particular, I hope to rewrite the Riemann-Stieltjes integral as a Riemann integral, where $d\alpha(x)\equiv g(x)dx$ and $g$ is an arbitrary probability density function. What kinds of restrictions does one need to place on $\alpha\in BV[a,b]$ to be able to achieve this?

Not every measure has a density with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Maybe the Radon-Nikodym theorem is what you're looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Formal_description

@Mittens What class of measures have densities (i.e. $\alpha^{\prime}$) with respect to Lebesgue measure? What are their characteristics?

@user775349: The absolutely continuous ones.

$\mu$ is a.c. with respect $\nu$ if $\mu(A)=0$ whenever $\nu(A)=0$.

If you had the stronger bound
$$
|L(f)|\le C\|f\|_2,\qquad\forall f\in C[a,b],
$$
where $\|f\|_2:=\sqrt{\int_a^b f(x)^2\,dx}$, then (Riesz-Fischer) there would be a square-integrable $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ such that
$$
L(f) = \int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx,\qquad \forall f\in C[a,b].
$$
That is, $d\alpha(x) =g(x)\,dx$. Note that this is a Lebesgue integral.
Similarly, if you had an $L^p$ bound rather than the $L^2$ bound above; in this case $g$ would lie in $L^q$.
